# Convert long data to wide in R

Tags: r, tidyr, reshape

I have the following data:

```
day = rep(c(24,25,26), 2)
status = c(1,1,1,0,0,0)
time = c(22313, 22106, 30192, 2340, 2219, 2401)
df = cbind.data.frame(day, status, time)
```

I want to reshape the data so that it goes from 6 rows to 3 (the days are no longer repeated) and I get a column for each type of status, and the time variable is converted to status1 and status0. Below is the final output I am looking for:

```
day = c(24,25,26)
time_status1 = c(22313, 22106, 30192)
time_status0 = c(2340, 2219, 2401)
df_new = cbind.data.frame(day, time_status0, time_status1)
df_new
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `pivot_wider` from the `tidyr` package:

```r
df |>
    dplyr::arrange(status) |> # Not necessary if order of columns not important
    tidyr::pivot_wider(
        names_from = status,
        values_from = time,
        names_prefix = "time_status"
    )

# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#     day time_status0 time_status1
#   <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>
# 1    24         2340        22313
# 2    25         2219        22106
# 3    26         2401        30192
```